# Windows system settings log

Tags: windows, windows-10, logging, event-log

Is windows logging changes in system/user settings?

Something is changing my mouse settings after each reboot. When booting with only basic devices and services, settings are preserved.

Can't find anything useful in event log.

Comment: By default No. Do you have some kind of extra software for your mouse? That might be the application changing the settings.

Comment: @Seth thx... it was Razer Synapse software, but still it would be nice to have this kind of logging... is it possible to turn it on while troubleshooting?

Comment: Not in an easy, comprehensible manner. You could use things like the sysinternals tools to get a better look and for certain events you can enable Windows Events but as far as I know it's not possible to have easy, readable messages for things like (most) system setting changes etc.